# How to play a sound file in java from src

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an mp3 file that i am trying to play from a source package in eclipse (java) for some reason it plays fine when i run it in eclipse but when i try to play it from a .jar it doesn't play. The images show up fine but the sound doesn't, i think i may have to recode the sound file like an image file but i'm not sure how here's the code for the Image:

```
JLabel TextBox = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/Images/TextBox.png"))));
```

and the Sound

```
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Sounds/Bonsai.mp3")));
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you verify the mp3 exists in the jar? In which path within the jar is it located?

Answer (score 1):

The:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(....)
```

does indeed return a URL. But MediaLocator can not use URL's from the form jar:file:/

I recommend to copy the file from the jar to a "Temp" filesystem and the stream it from there.
You can always delete it when you done, if that is needed.

Comment: Your answer is not correct. I retrieve files every day from a jar using getResourceAsStream

Comment: That was not my point, to my knowledge the MediaLocator needs an URL not a stream. and the MediaLocator can not handle file:// URL's. But your solution can work let hubbardh test.

Comment: @Frank - Read the javadoc - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the resource as a Stream. You can retrieve a file this way.

```
InputStream fis = 
    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Sounds/bonsai.mp3");
p = new Player(fis);
p.play();
```